# Consensus dendrogram using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, consensus

I construct five different dendrograms using the `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` library (the dendrogram and linkage specifically) and now I need to do a consensus dendrogram based on these five dendrograms, but I'm not getting anywhere.

I thought of saving the result in other format also used by other packages (like the newick format used in Biopython) but I'm struggling in converting the scipy output to these formats.

Does anyone there know how to find a consensus tree/dendrogram/matrix using Python?

I'm sorry, I'm kinda noob at this, maybe there are other packages that I can't find or something. Here's what I have tried:

```py
# Importing the needed libraries 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# Importing datasets (5 web foods, in this case)

w1 = pd.read_table(r"C:\Users\catar\Desktop\Thesis_related\UPGMA\web1.txt")
invertw1 = pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.pinv(w1.values), w1.columns, w1.index)

# And I made this 5 times (for different webs)
# UPGMA construction

Z1e = linkage(invertw1, 'average','euclidean') # Also times 5

# And then I made the dendrogram / plot:
# Calculate full dendrogram

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram - Network1', fontweight='bold', fontsize=20, y=1.03)
plt.xlabel('Different analysed indexes', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15, labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('Distance', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15, labelpad=20) d1 = dendrogram( Z1e, color_threshold=0, above_threshold_color='k', labels=invertw1.index, )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide relevant code you tried so far.

Comment: # Importing the needed libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# Importing datasets (5 web foods, in this case)
w1 = pd.read_table(r"C:\Users\catar\Desktop\Thesis_related\UPGMA\web1.txt")
invertw1 = pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.pinv(w1.values), w1.columns, w1.index)
# And I made this 5 times (for different webs)

# UPGMA construction
Z1e = linkage(invertw1, 'average','euclidean')
# Also times 5

Comment: And then I made the dendrogram / plot:

# Calculate full dendrogram
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram - Network1', fontweight='bold', fontsize=20, y=1.03)
plt.xlabel('Different analysed indexes', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15, labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('Distance', fontweight='bold', fontsize=15, labelpad=20)
d1 = dendrogram(
        Z1e,
        color_threshold=0,
        above_threshold_color='k',
        labels=invertw1.index,
)
plt.show()